# What ICC printer profile should I select for cardstock paper?

Tags: printing, printer, color-profiles, canon-pixma

I need to print some comics on cardstock paper (210 GSM). It's not by any particular brand but let's say I did get one from some reputed paper company. I've been searching around for printer profiles so that I can print proper colors onto this cardstock.

I've been searching around on various sites for color profiles but I don't see any ICC profile available anywhere for cardstock paper. There's all kinds of profiles for art, glossy or matte paper. But there's nothing available for cardstock.

Here's an example: https://www.moabpaper.com/icc-profiles-downloads

1. Does anyone know why there's nothing available for cardstock paper? Companies do sell it but strangely don't offer the ICC profiles for them.
2. Which ICC profile might be closest to the cardstock paper?

Comment: Is the rest of your pre-press workflow calibrated? If not, don't bother.

Answer (score 2):

1. I'd say; as you normally do not print pictures taken with a camera on other papers than those aimed for that purpose.
2. Well, not those aimed for glossy paper at least, unless your cardstock is similar to glossy paper; maybe try those for "Watercolor", "Matte" or "Velvet" - but also those might be hit and miss.

If you have a calibrated display and a printer/paper calibration device ([example](https://spyderx.datacolor.com/shop-products/printer-profiling/)), that would probably be the most straight forward option.

In the end; You may well find that refraining from use of any color profiles may give the nicest result... as to get all this "right" requires meticulous work; one step missing or bad and the result may be worse than without.

Also note: A calibrated workflow aims to get the same colors throughout, from screen to final product (e.g. print), i.e. that does not necessarily mean "the nicest colors". As with "bottle necks" you will see and hit limits; which might be *THE* reason to use profiles:
Your screen will show an emulated version of the print, and also show where you have a paper gamut problem (i.e. what image parts will/can not (be) print(ed) as intended).

*One more note: If you're on Linux, check which software to use; the software provided for Windows will generally not be available. This may well limit your hardware choices; "example" above has not been good in that regard.*

Yet one more note: If you do not have an inkjet (or possibly sublimation) printer, then calibration is futile in my experience; especially so with printers that come close to laser-tech.

Ref: A list of calibration devices that Linux software may have success with; https://www.argyllcms.com/doc/instruments.html,
this may be seen as a starting point on selecting what hardware to purchase when using other OS'es.

Comment: Kudos for even attempting to tackle this. I would consider this one of those tasks best included under the general heading of "The holy grail for the uninformed." I've been doing graphics for 30 years & before that I was a litho printer… & I still don't know how to actually teach someone how to do this properly without many days of trial & error, even if they spend a fortune on colorimeter/spectrophotometer hardware [ or even if they move from Windows to Mac, which is always a good start ;) In the OP's last question on this topic I recommended going to Snappy Snaps… & I wasn't really joking.

Comment: Well ;-) - I cannot claim to be "pro" in this area, I'm sharing my experiences (possibly reaching a prosumer level)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with a generic ICC solution.  You didn't mention printer, paper, or ink brand (not that this would solve the problem).

As @Tetsujin points out (indirectly), color matching is an art and takes years of practice to know what to tweak.  I wrote color print drivers / ICC profiles for 8 years and can tell you (also) that getting it right for RGB or CYMK takes A LOT of trial and error even if you know what you are doing and have the tools to measure ACTUAL colors coming out on your print medium with expensive tools like colorimeter/spectrophotometer hardware. You do color matching to the screen first, then a scanner (or more expensive tool).. then you start tweaking the profile.

ICC profiles ***are specific to three+ components***, not one. The actual printer, the ink, and the paper.  Speed of print, the resolution, and other hardware specific factors can also come into play for most printers being that this determines the amount of spray or toner being pulled/put to the page.

Although it is a bit odd that there are generic profiles at all, I guess they would indeed get you *closer* most of the time.

I myself would suggest that if you didn't INTEND on becoming an expert at this, eyeball it using generic profiles and get a biological female to help (if you aren't one).  [They perceive colors better/different than us biological males](https://phys.org/news/2004-09-superior-women.html).
When the XX chromosome say pull the trigger, if you agree..  Go.

I hope this helps.